How to track function return value in Dart
I need to track a String function return value in Dartprogram.
My program is working, but I cannot figure out what my function is doing.
I need to see a function return value like 'abc' or blank or something else.
Using breakpoints does not show the value.
Do you know what I could use to see the actual value?
If I know the actual value, then I could easily see what my function code is doing wrong.

What do you mean breakpoints do not show the value? That is a major use of breakpoints. The value is shown somewhere in your IDE.

Could you please explain how to see a variable value using breakpoints. The breakpoints run a program from line x to line y. Where do you need look to see the function return value or a variable value?

What IDE are you using? There should be a debug tab or variables subwindow somewhere that shows variables at your breakpoint. Click around a bit when you hit your breakpoint

I am using Android Studio. I should open the Debug tab and type a variable name, and now I can see the variable value.  The issue is solved! Thank You

This question is similar to: Is it possible to watch variables at runtime?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar, but Android Studio changed a lot, and the reply in this link is no longer relevant although ideas presented are worth thinking about. I liked the TOAST approach(now called AlertDialog). Please note that I need to track function return value, not simply a variable. Thank You

You could temporarily wrap your function call with
T traceReturn<T>(T returned) {
  debugPrint('something unique: $returned');
  return returned;
}

